# C#: Conversion to TimeSpan is not retaining complete value

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I get this issue while converting a string value to TimeSpan.

The values are like : "hrs:mm:ss:ms"
eg: "00:00:10:03"

While converting this value to TimeSpan, the leading part gets truncated.

Code :

```
TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan();
TimeSpan.TryParse("00:00:10:03" , out span);
```

Output : 
00:10:03

How can i retain the entire value in Timespan only

Comment: It's very odd for a number of milliseconds to be expressed as "03". Is that meant to be 30 milliseconds or 3? If it's 3, why is it formatted to *two* digits? Additionally, you need to differentiate between the output *as a TimeSpan* and what happens when you call ToString.

Answer (score 0):

`TimeSpan.TryParse` doesn`t recognize your format. Instead use

```
span = TimeSpan.ParseExact("00:00:10:03", @"hh\:mm\:ss\:ff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use span.Ticks in output

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z48198e(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private static void ParseTimeSpan(string intervalStr)
{
  // Write the first part of the output line.
  Console.Write( "{0,20}   ", intervalStr );

  // Parse the parameter, and then convert it back to a string.
  TimeSpan intervalVal; 
  if (TimeSpan.TryParse(intervalStr, out intervalVal)) 
  {
     string intervalToStr = intervalVal.ToString();

     // Pad the end of the TimeSpan string with spaces if it 
     // does not contain milliseconds.
     int pIndex = intervalToStr.IndexOf(':');
     pIndex = intervalToStr.IndexOf('.', pIndex);
     if (pIndex < 0)
        intervalToStr += "        ";

     Console.WriteLine("{0,21}", intervalToStr);
     // Handle failure of TryParse method.
  }
  else
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Parse operation failed.");
  }
}
```

Call them like:

```
ParseTimeSpan("0");
    ParseTimeSpan("14");
    ParseTimeSpan("1:2:3");
    ParseTimeSpan("0:0:0.250");
    ParseTimeSpan("10.20:30:40.50");
    ParseTimeSpan("99.23:59:59.9999999");
    ParseTimeSpan("0023:0059:0059.0099");
    ParseTimeSpan("23:0:0");
    ParseTimeSpan("24:0:0");
    ParseTimeSpan("0:59:0");
    ParseTimeSpan("0:60:0");
    ParseTimeSpan("0:0:59");
    ParseTimeSpan("0:0:60");
    ParseTimeSpan("10:");
    ParseTimeSpan("10:0");
    ParseTimeSpan(":10");
    ParseTimeSpan("0:10");
    ParseTimeSpan("10:20:");
    ParseTimeSpan("10:20:0");
    ParseTimeSpan(".123");
    ParseTimeSpan("0.12:00");
    ParseTimeSpan("10.");
    ParseTimeSpan("10.12");
    ParseTimeSpan("10.12:00");
```